# htaccess trying to rewrite rule all to one path except urls that start with admin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite all incoming URLs to `test.php?url=party/$1`, except for URLs that start with admin. They need to go to `test.php?url=admin/$1`, but I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong. Anyone got an idea?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?url=party/$1 [PT,L]
    RewriteRule ^admin(.*)$ test.php?url=admin$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ test.php?url=admin/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ test.php?url=party/$1 [PT,L]
```